# Edit pixels in a GeoTIFF while preserving ALL metadata

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, osgeo

I'm having an issue where I need to read in a GeoTIFF, modify some pixel values (setting specific locations to the NODATA value), and then overwrite the original GeoTIFF.

The trick is I want to preserve ALL of the metadata and structure of the original GeoTIFF. This includes overviews and tiling, as well as any RPCs, CRS, transforms, or other metadata.

I attempted to do this with `gdal_calc.py`, but I found that it didn't preserve overviews. It also wasn't able to correctly preserve the original nodata values.

I also attempted to do this with `rasterio`, but it ended up again not preserving overviews and it also added origin and pixelsize information that wasn't previously there.

I've also looked at potentially using `osgeo` itself, but I again hit the overview issue. I know how to get the number of overviews for an existing GeoTIFF so I can add them on later, but I don't know how to find the overview resampling that was used in an existing GeoTIFF. Does that information even exist?

Furthermore, because this is running on unseen data, I'm not sure how to ensure I'm copying over all the tags / metadata that could possibly be in the source GeoTIFF.

Here is the code I've been playing with so far, where I've tried to do this with rasterio and gdal_calc.py:

```py
    import kwimage
    import numpy as np
    data = (np.random.rand(256, 256) * 100).astype(np.int16)
    data[20:30, 20:80] = -9999
    data[90:120, 30:50] = 0
    src_fpath = 'test.tif'
    dst_fpath = 'result.tif'
    kwimage.imwrite(src_fpath, data, backend='gdal', nodata_value=-9999, overviews=4)

    import rasterio as rio
    src = rio.open(src_fpath, 'r')
    dst = rio.open(dst_fpath, 'w', **src.profile)

    nodata_value = -9999

    with rio.open(src_fpath, 'r') as src:
        src.profile
        new = src.read()
        mask = (new == 0)
        nodata_value = -9999
        new[mask] = nodata_value
        with rio.open(dst_fpath, 'w', **src.profile) as dst:
            dst.write(new)

    foo = kwimage.imread('result.tif')
    """
    gdal_calc.py -A test.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="(-9999 * (A == 0)) + ((A != 0) * A)"
    echo "----"
    gdalinfo test.tif
    echo "----"
    gdalinfo result.tif

    """
```

##### MWE with gdal_calc.py

To reproduce the gdal_calc.py claim, I setup a dummy geotiff:

```py
    # Create a COG with tiles / overviews / nodata
    import kwimage
    import numpy as np
    data = (np.random.rand(256, 256) * 100).astype(np.int16)
    data[20:30, 20:80] = -9999
    data[90:120, 30:50] = 0
    src_fpath = 'test.tif'
    dst_fpath = 'result.tif'
    kwimage.imwrite(src_fpath, data, backend='gdal', nodata_value=-9999, overviews=4)
```

And then try to use gdal calc to move the zeros to the desired nodata value.

```bash
    gdal_calc.py -A test.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="(-9999 * (A == 0)) + ((A != 0) * A)"
    echo "----"
    gdalinfo test.tif
    echo "----"
    gdalinfo result.tif
```

The result is:

```
----
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 256, 256
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
  LAYOUT=COG
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  256.0)
Upper Right (  256.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  256.0,  256.0)
Center      (  128.0,  128.0)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
  Overviews: 128x128, 64x64, 32x32, 16x16
----
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: result.tif
Size is 256, 256
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  256.0)
Upper Right (  256.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  256.0,  256.0)
Center      (  128.0,  128.0)
Band 1 Block=256x16 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-32768
```

Showing that the overviews are not carried over, and the existing -9999 nodata value was incorrectly modified in addition to transforming the existings zeros into the desired -9999 nodata value.

##### MWE with osgeo

UPDATE: 2022-12-23

I've gotten a behavior that roughly works with osgeo by using CreateCopy to make a copy of an existing dataset in memory, and then modify it there before writing it out again. However, this still has the pain point that I don't know the resampling algorithm, and I also have the COG settings hard-coded, and it would be better if I could lift them from the source image.

```py
    fpath = 'test.tif'
    new_fpath = 'result.tif'

    correct_nodata_value = -9999

    from osgeo import gdal
    src_dset = gdal.Open(fpath, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    assert src_dset.RasterCount == 1
    src_band = src_dset.GetRasterBand(1)
    num_overviews = src_band.GetOverviewCount()

    driver1 = gdal.GetDriverByName(str('MEM'))
    copy1 = driver1.CreateCopy(str(''), src_dset)
    src_dset.FlushCache()
    src_dset = None

    # Modify the pixel contents
    band = copy1.GetRasterBand(1)
    band_data = band.ReadAsArray()
    band_data[band_data == 0] = correct_nodata_value
    curr_nodat_value = band.GetNoDataValue()
    band.WriteArray(band_data)
    if curr_nodat_value != correct_nodata_value:
        band.SetNoDataValue(correct_nodata_value)

    overviewlist = (2 ** np.arange(1, num_overviews + 1)).tolist()
    copy1.BuildOverviews('AVERAGE', overviewlist)

    _options = [
        'BIGTIFF=YES',
        'TILED=YES',
        'BLOCKXSIZE={}'.format(256),
        'BLOCKYSIZE={}'.format(256),
    ]
    _options += ['COMPRESS={}'.format('DEFLATE')]
    _options.append('COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES')

    # Flush the in-memory dataset to an on-disk GeoTiff
    driver1 = None
    driver2 = gdal.GetDriverByName(str('GTiff'))
    copy2 = driver2.CreateCopy(new_fpath, copy1, options=_options)
    copy2.FlushCache()
    copy1 = None
    copy2 = None  # NOQA
    driver2 = None
```

##### Final thoughts

I suppose I might have to punt somewhat on carrying over everything. I can carry over most of the metadata I know about manually, but the overview resampling is something I'm having a hard time with. Is the resampling algorithm used to construct overviews even stored as metadata?

To summarize the question is:

- Is there an `osgeo` way to copy all metadata from one GeoTIFF to another new one?

Comment: One question per Question, please.

Comment: The question is: how do I copy all metadata from a source geotiff to a destination geotiff. The question seems complex, so I thought breaking into smaller pieces would be helpful.

Comment: Bullet lists of questions are a closure magnet for lack of *focus*.

Comment: If you edit the full resolution pixels then the overviews are changing as well and need refreshing. But you can probably keep the outdated overviews if they are created as external .ovr file. Please give a re-producible test case for gdal_calc about this "It also wasn't able to correctly preserve the original nodata values."

Comment: @user30184 I added the MWE that reproduce the gdal_calc issue. I've also added a pure osgeo partial solution that is pretty close to what I want, but lacks proper handling of drive options and overviews (not even sure if correct overview handling is possible).

Comment: Ok, I understand better now. What you want to do is complicated but you seem to be close with your own code. The resampling method of the overviews is not stored anywhere if the creator of the original GeoTIFF has not saved it as custom metadata.